# What can be used as a unique USB device identifier aside from serial number?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, unique

I'm making a USB desktop locker, much like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/832065/A-Simple-USB-desktop-locker) one but I'm trying to make it work with other USB devices (mice, kb, anything really). Are there any other unique info I can use aside from a serial number? Are there ways to access these from .NET? (C# specifically)

(I had some usb devices without a serial number, mostly from China)

Comment: What happens if the USB device breaks? how are you planing to unlock your computer?

Comment: USB:Main unlocking method;;Password:Backup in case all else fails.

I will also implement redundancy (i.e. multiple devices)

Comment: Does it have to be something that is hard wired into the USB device?
Another solution is to generate some kind of hash based on a unique combination of the time when the USB is plugged in the computer (or your software loads if this happens after) and some salt, and whenever the USB is removed and re-plugged all you have to do is check if the hash exists in a specific location in the USB device. if it exists, overwrite it with a new hash. if not, keep the computer locked.

Comment: Does it have to be hard wired? No, but that would be nice. That solution? It will work, but on a storage device only. What about a smart card reader? or a mouse?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that you are talking about USB Storage since the article you linked to is talking about that. if you want something to work on all USB devices, I have no suggestion for that.

Comment: I guess I might fall back to using device storage with key files. There are too many USB devices without unique identifiers (they do but they're not unique)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use USB VID and PID. Not the best way, but atleast it is one. When you are able to use a unique ID, then use it too. You can use hashfunctions to combine them too.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, but VID and PID are easily reproduced by simply having the same USB device. I realized I didn't give this question much thought.

Comment: same USB brand, model, etc.

Comment: That is why I said "Not the best way, but atleast it is one.". I don't think, that there is a better way.

Comment: Yes yes. I think so too.